# Having an issue with jQuery in python3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with a submit form function that I cannot seem to resolve. It is probably something simple but my form submit does not seem to connect to my script file. I'll do my best to show everything.

This is the Base Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>User Login</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">

</head>
<body>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

<script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the Homepage:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <h1 class="center">Create an Account</h1>
        <form name="signup_form">

            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="field" required>

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="field" required>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="field" required>

            <p class="error error--hidden"></p>

            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is my scripts.js file:

```
$("form[name=signup_form]").submit(function(e) {

var $form = $(this);
var $error = $form.find(".error");
var data = $form.serialize();
console.log("working?")

$.ajax({
    url: "/user/signup",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    },
    error: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    }
})

e.preventDefault();
})
```

On form submit it does not console.log("working?") so it is not getting to this file. I'm just following a YouTube tutorial and I'm stumped. I'm guessing it's something simple but I've fried my brain trying to figure it out. Also .submit in scripts.js has a strike through it and on hover says "Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element."

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Untagging Python as this is a purely jQuery issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have messed up brackets in this line
`$("form[name=signup_form").submit(function(e) {`

Comment: Correct, though you don't actually explain the solution.

Comment: Whoops I did, I fixed that just now (*added closing "]"*). Still with that fix it does not seem to work